# vue single file component fails to load styles

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gagarin-qxp98?file=/src/components/GenericItem.vue:1921-1957

I'm trying to display a modal that needs styling. Using

```
<style scoped>
@import "../styles/modal-style.css";
</style>
```

does not load the appropriate styles, nor does pasting the contents of

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gagarin-qxp98?file=/src/styles/modal-style.css:0-1064

into the `style` tag.

The idea is to get something like

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-tdd-jrrgg?file=/index.html:122-181

but the modal is a single file component.

Why doesn't vue load styles?

Comment: its loading fine, it's just that for example your targeting `.modal-header h3` but the default slot has no h3, so it's not green

Comment: Tried to add add wrap the modal into an `h3` styling did change but not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create alias in such cases inside your webpack config file like so:

```
... your webpack config ...

configureWebpack: {  
 resolve: {  
   alias: {  
     '~styles': path.resolve(_dirname, 'path/to/your/styles.css')
   }
 }
}
```

Your alias will be global now so you will be able to do so:

```
<style scoped>
    @import '~styles';
</styles>
```

Comment: Apparently it's not related to the loader (the example in the question has no explicit webpack config

Comment: `vue.config.js`  is not loaded https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jepsen-r7283?file=/vue.config.js:56-376