# vue.config.js does not seem to load

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, less

In:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jepsen-r7283?file=/vue.config.js

based on:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68308416/1079483

`vue.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "modal-styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/styles/modal-style.css")
      }
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        modifyVars: {},
        javascriptEnabled: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

is not loaded by vue-cli. The idea is to replicate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cs-vue-cli-3-vj2rl?file=/vue.config.js

When reaching the `styles` tag of `EditCategory.vue`:

```
<style scoped>
@import 'modal-styles';
</style>
```

the alias cannot be read:

```
TypeError
Path must be a string. Received null
r
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.7be24d846.chunk.js:1:246770
Object.isAbsolute
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.7be24d846.chunk.js:1:247916
(anonymous function)
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/vendors~postcss-compiler~vue-style-compiler.f9e51cefa.chunk.js:1:1069
(anonymous function)
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/vendors~postcss-compiler~vue-style-compiler.f9e51cefa.chunk.js:1:1060
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
This error overlay is powered by `react-error-overlay` used in `create-react-app`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path was wrong in `style`:

```
<style>
  @import '/src/styles/modal-style.css';
</style>
```